# How to automate Azure web app deployment to pick latest image from azure container

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-web-app-service

An Azure container registry is setup with a repository.

The Azure WebApp is published with Source specified as the container and the docker image tag is selected in the dropdown.

Using Jenkins the new build is made and the docker image is pushed to container repository in Azure.

But how to ensure the webapp automatically picks the latest image to be deployed.

Currently from the web app's deployment center we need to select the image and the **latest pushed tag** manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate your App Service, click Deployment Center, in the Settings tab, enable Continuous Deployment.

[image]

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ci-cd-custom-container?tabs=acr&pivots=container-linux)

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, enabled the continuous deployment setting however still the latest image was not deployed automatically.
Also, wanted to mention that the registry source is not Private Registry but it is **Azure container registry**.

I can see the new image gets uploaded successfully in the azure container but in the **deployment center** the new image tag need to be selected manually still else it keeps running the older version.

Comment: After updating an image in the registry, getting the new image in App Service can take a few minutes.  I'd suggest that you create a test App Service to test if this works for you.

Comment: The continuous deployment seems to work only if the image name is "latest", and all the new images must be built with the **"latest"** tag.
Alternatively, wanted to know if there is any azure cli command to re-deploy the azure web app specifying any custom image tag in the command, so that the tag does not need to be latest.

Comment: az webapp config container set https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of days investigating why azure does not redeploy new image automatically. Just enabling Continuous Deployment is not enough

***What worked for me:***

- To trigger Azure web app to redeploy the last image from the registry - you need to trigger Webhook URL. You can try it in postman.
  "Locate to Deployment center => "Registry settings" => "WebhookURL". Just take URL from 'Webhook URL' field and send Http **POST** request
  to it.

It works with 'latest' tag and any other tags.

[Screenshot from Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QvkA.png)
*(And you don't need to register webhook in azure container registry)*

I've created separate step in my github actions workflow that sends PING request to the Webhook URL